# Show and Hide Modal Popup Extender Not working

Tags: c#, ajax, modalpopupextender

Hi all I have a modal popup extender set to a hidden linkbutton.  So when I want to use it I am doing

```
protected void ProcessFileBtn_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WaitModalPopupExtender.Show();
    //DO STUFF
    WaitModalPopupExtender.Hide();
}
```

Process takes a while, but no Modal Pop Up extender shows, when I create a button just to do the show function it works, but when I add in this

```
protected void Test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WaitModalPopupExtender.Show();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    WaitModalPopupExtender.Hide();

}
```

Nothing shows up.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work.
Why...??
First request sent to Server.

```
WaitModalPopupExtender.Show();----Executed---But no response send to Client
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);----Executed---But no response send to Client
WaitModalPopupExtender.Hide();----Executed---Now its time to send the response
```

Now you can expect the output that will be sent to the Client

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all of the code it's hard to tell, but I believe that the page is doing a `PostBack` when you click the linkbutton. When the page does a postback, it refreshes and therefore your `ModalPopupExtender` won't show. I think you're looking for and `Ajax` call to do what you want, which I'm pretty sure is showing a wait window while processing data.

Comment: Yes, the popup is the Wait window